# how to make custom query from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

We have 3 different tables
ie. users, daily_status, status_types

fields in tables

user :

```
id,
name,
department_id
```

data for user table:

```
u1 jai 1
u2 singh 1
u3 test 2
```

daily_status:

```
id,
user_id,
status_id,
date
```

data for daily_status table:

```
1 u1 2 '23/10/2013'
2 u1 3 '24/10/2013'
3 u2 3 '23/10/2013'
4 u3 2 '23/10/2013'
5 u3 2 '23/10/2013'
```

status_types:

```
id,
status_name,
```

data for status_types table

```
1 present
2 leave
3 sick
```

I need to make a query like this

```
SELECT user.id, user.name status.name 
LEFT JOIN daily_status as ds ON (user.id=ds.user_id)
LEFT JOIN status_types as status ON (ds.status_id=status.id)
WHERE user.department_id=1 AND ds.date='24/10/2013'
```

current results:

```
u1 jai sick
```

but I want

```
u1 jai sick
u2 singh -
```

The results are good as per query but I need to reconfigure it so that it gives me details of all users of that department those who don't have a status on that date in daily_status table.

Comment: *don't have a status on that date* which status ? or all statuses

Comment: I mean that for whom status has not been fed into database yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the date validation to the ON:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, status.status_name 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN daily_status as ds ON u.id=ds.user_id AND ds.date='24/10/2013'
LEFT JOIN status_types as status ON ds.status_id=status.id
WHERE u.department_id=1
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f25d0/9)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you do an OUTER JOIN and put a WHERE somethingFromMyLeftJoinedTable = "something" you will only get results where "something" exists in the LEFT JOINed table.

To solve this you could either move the WHERE date= 'xxx' to the JOIN part of the query like this

```
SELECT user.id, user.name status.name 
LEFT JOIN daily_status as ds ON user.id=ds.user_id AND ds.date = '24/10/2013'
LEFT JOIN status_types as status ON (ds.status_id=status.id)
WHERE user.department_id=1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT user.id, user.name status.name 
 from user
 LEFT JOIN daily_status as ds ON (user.id=ds.user_id AND ds.date='24/10/2013')
 LEFT JOIN status_types as status ON (ds.status_id=status.id)
 WHERE user.department_id=1 and ds.id is null
```

or try this

```
 SELECT user.id, user.name ,'' as  statusname 
 from user
where user.id not in 
(select ds.user_id from 
daily_status as ds 
LEFT JOIN status_types as status ON (ds.status_id=status.id)
WHERE user.department_id=1 and ds.date = '24/10/2013')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm over simplifying this but you only have one record that has the given date 24/10/2013 so only one can show.

If you have more than one listing for a person on a given date you could do something like this

```
SELECT a.id,a.[name],status_types.status_name FROM(SELECT id,[user].[name],department_id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY[user].[name]ORDER BY ID DESC)rn FROM[user])a LEFT JOIN daily_status AS ds ON(a.id=ds.user_id)LEFT JOIN status_types ON(ds.status_id=status_types.id)WHERE a.department_id=1AND rn=1AND ds.date='2013-10-23'
```